# Change to case in folders are not reflected in intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

When I rename folders in VSCode intellisense gets confused.  Is there a way to reset intellisense?

[image]

Comment: You can follow these [steps](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/715)

Answer (score 2):

If you run the `Reload Window` command from the VS Command Palette it will restart the analysis server, which will reanalyse and should fix things up.

However, this seems like a nasty bug. Would you mind running the `Dart: Capture Logs` command, reproducing the issue and then [opening an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues) with the log (please review it for anything sensitive) and detailed steps so we can investigate?